# android studio button textwiew gestures

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, textview

They are constantly moving how do I make them fixed

I made a random application but when you press the button, the textview and button are constantly changing. How can I prevent this? As below pictures

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enxpc.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRWIM.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0ycH.jpg)

the codes I use in these

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw1"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:text="random"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Can you give us your Java code? where did you set listeners on this button? And maybe don't use centerInParent with alignParentBottom. If you want to center your button in a horizontal line just use centerHorizontal. This way you are pushing it to the bottom and want it to the center of the layout.

Comment: public void onClick(View p1)

Comment: That's not what I mean. Edit your question and put your Activity.class code in there.

Comment: I am using aide on the phone. That's why I can't find the file you said. I just want to pin the button.

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a **LinearLayout** and its children are laid out horizontally by default. Based on the length of the text in your **TextView** is '*pushing*' the **Button** to the right (horizontally). If you want to change this behavior consider using a different layout or change the orientation of the current **LinearLayout** by doing so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

[LinearLayout children orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPuZ7.png)

Comment: This is why full code is important in the question. Nice!